# Set node name in puppet to noop option

Tags: puppet

I'm using puppet and want to test it with noop, but some configuration depends on the hostname like the node types.

How can I set the node name and run puppet with noop to check the node configuration that match the node name?, currently i got this as error message (my laptop is solaria):

Could not find default node or by name with 'solaria, solaria.lan' on node solaria.lan

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
puppetd --test --noop --fqdn="hostname.example.com"
```

Or with 2.6, this may be preferable:

```
puppet agent --test --noop--fqdn="hostname.example.com"
```

This will tend to create new certificates on the puppet master, so you'll probably need to run  `puppetca --clean hostname.example.com` on the puppet master afterwords, otherwise when you finally get hosts with those names they'll be unable to set up an SSL relationship with the master.

Answer (score -1):

I just figure out one possible solution, adding this to my config file

```
nodename = cert
certname = hostname
```

Comment: Well, I'm currently using env FACTER_XXX=value FACTER_yyy=value puppet and facter will do the trick for me.